# How do I display the taxonomy for a custom post type in an array

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I am trying to display the terms from a taxonomy on my archive page but I am struggling to display the terms name, here is what I have so far:

```
if ($post->post_type == 'cpt_saving') {
   $categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'cpt_saving-type');
   if ($categories) {
       $categories['name'];
   }
   $stack = [
        'title' => get_field('savings_headline', $post_id),
        'image' => get_field('savings_supplier_logo', $post_id),
        'reference' => get_field('savings_reference', $post_id),
        'date' => get_the_date('l j F Y'),
        'link' => get_the_permalink(),
        'term' => $categories->name,
    ];
    get_template_partial('partials/savings/savings-item', $stack);
}
```

As I have $stack as my array how would I call the taxonomy terms name to display it on the front end?

Comment: Have you tried print_r($stack['term']) (or with var_dump() to see if it outputs something?

Comment: `get_the_terms` returns an array (not single) of `WP_Term` objects. You'd want to loop through them and get the `$name` from each. 

If you want just the first then something around `$categories[0]->name` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to display the taxonomy term for each post using the following:

```
$savings_terms = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'cpt_saving-type');

$stack = [
  'term' => strip_tags($savings_terms),
];
```

This output the current term for each post and doesn't throw an error when a post doesn't have a term assigned to it, it worked best for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been noted, you can do this by iterating over each of the terms, which are [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) objects. Each of those [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) objects has a `name` property. So you'd do it like this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'cpt_saving-type' );
$terms = is_array( $terms ) ? $terms : array();

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name.'<br />'; // Outputs each name.
}
```

Comment: I had already tried this prior to posting my question, unfortunately it doesn't work as it displays the same taxonomy term for all posts (even those without a term assigned to them). I have posted my solution below...